# Intermittent Test Failure when Checking for Unique Field Constraint in Mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mocking, ts-jest

I am having an issue with one of my Jest tests that verifies the uniqueness of an `access_code` field in a Mongoose model. The test intermittently fails and I can't seem to pinpoint why.

Here's the test code:

```js
it('should not allow duplicate access_code', async () => {
    const accessCode = 'unique-code';
    await User.create({ access_code: accessCode });
    const userWithDuplicateCode = new User({ access_code: accessCode });

    try {
      await userWithDuplicateCode.save();
      throw new Error('User was saved with duplicate access_code.');
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.log(err.message);
      expect(err.code).toBe(11000);
    }
});
```

The error I occasionally get is:
Expected: 11000
Received: undefined

Additionally, I see the log: "User was saved with duplicate access_code.", which indicates that the second user is sometimes saved without an error being thrown.

The access_code field in my Mongoose model is set as unique:

```js
import mongoose, { Document } from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

export type UserDocument = Document & {
access_code: string;
email: string;
googleId: string;
};

const userSchema = new Schema\<UserDocument\>({
access_code: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
email: String,
googleId: String,
});

export const User = mongoose.model\<UserDocument\>('User', userSchema);
```

the test is occasionally failing. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any insights on what might be happening?

Thanks in advance!

Here's what I've checked/tried:

Ensured that the access_code has a unique constraint.
Made sure to clear the database before each test run.